# Cumulative distribution function of a model similar to the multinominal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, absolute-value

I would like to solve a problem similar to the multinominal distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution):

- For k independent trials each of which leads to a success for exactly one of n categories, I would like to know the 
  distribution of the absolute values (or modulus - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of the categories.
- The fixed success probability of each category is 1/n.

My model as an urn problem:

- n colored balls - all of different color
- k draws (ball is placed back in the urn)

What is the probability, that I drew balls of just one color (the same ball k times); what is the probability that I drew balls of exactly two different (arbitrary) colors; .. three different (arbitrary) colors; and so on.

The multinominal distribution does not fit as it gives the probability of any particular combination of numbers of successes for the various categories
and not the absolute values of categories.
Our model is a bit simplified, as the success probability of all categories is the same.

Is there a distribution describing my model?

Comment: What does absolute value of the categories mean? Are some of the categories negative numbers?

Comment: No, they are just nominal arbitrary numbers. For the ease of understanding, let's say the categories are called 1, 2, ..., n.
To make clear what I mean by absolute value I would like to characterize my model as a urn problem:
For k independent trials, what is the probability, that I draw

Comment: (edited and tried to clarify my initial question): **absolute value** = **number of differnt categories occured**